# How do I use SetWindowText with Unicode in Win32 using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, win32gui

I'm trying to use PowerShell to change a Window title to display emojis.

I can change the Window title of a process (that has a window) using...

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Win32 {
  [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowText")]
  public static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string strTitle);
}
"@

$MyNotepadProcess = start-process notepad -PassThru
```

```
[Win32]::SetWindowText($MyNotepadProcess.MainWindowHandle, 'My Title')
```

[image]

But using `SetWindowText` with emoji-codes just garbles the emoji characters in the output...

Using `SetWindowTextW` garbles the output for anything I pass to the function...

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Win32 {
  [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint="SetWindowTextW")]
  public static extern int SetWindowTextW(IntPtr hWnd, string strTitle);
}
"@

$MyNotepadProcess = start-process notepad -PassThru
```

```
[Win32]::SetWindowTextW($MyNotepadProcess.MainWindowHandle, 'My Title')
```

[image]

One issue I think I have, is that SetWindowTextW only accept wide string, but I don't know how to provide that as input.
And then I need to add the emojis using the Unicode numbers as in `u{1F600} (that's a :) too you).

(See [Get Started with Win32 and C++ - Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings))

Comment: Why are you trying to use SetWindowTextW? The unicode version is SetWindowText, which you already said is working

Comment: Because I didn't got SetWindowText to work with emojis I tried a function that forces the use of Unicode.

Comment: @TheEvilMetal, using `SetWindowText` without `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode` calls the _ANSI_ implementation, i.e. `SetWindowTextA`

Comment: @TheEvilMetal I clarfied my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to ensure that the Unicode version of a WinAPI function is called properly is to:

- Add `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode` to the `[DllImport]` attribute.
- *Omit* the `W` suffix from the function name.

```
// Note the use of "CharSet=CharSet.Unicode" and 
// the function name *without suffix*
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string strTitle);
```

This ensures that `SetWindowTextW`, i.e. the *Unicode* implementation of the function is called, *and* that .NET marshals the .NET string essentially as-is as as a native `LPCWSTR` string, i.e. as a null-terminated array of Unicode code units.